# Continue with 'next' image using cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

I have images saved as 'image_1.jpg', 'image_2.jpg', etc.
When 'next' button is clicked, a new image loads. A variable name 'rightnow' is used to increment the number and change the URL in img src attr. I am trying to store the value of this variable in cookies so that it continues the next image load even when a new session is used.

I checked the cookie value in the browser, that is getting set fine. But when I actually use a new session, it seems use the value '1' for variable 'rightnow' and shows the first image. What's wrong with my code? (Using jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.3.1)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var highone=9; 
var rightnow=$.cookie("mycookieismine");
if (rightnow=='NaN') { rightnow=1;} 
      $("#next-img").click(function(){
        rightnow=rightnow+1; if (rightnow>highone) {rightnow=1;}; 
        $(".imga-class").attr('src',"http://example.com/images/image_"+rightnow+".jpg");
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
        var date = new Date();
        var minutes = 10;
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        $.cookie("mycookieismine",rightnow, { expires: date }); 
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug (or two) on this line:

```
if (rightnow=='NaN') { rightnow=1;}
```

Consider the initial case where no cookies have been set. The variable rightnow will be null because $.cookie("mycookieismine"); returns null.

**null is not equal to NaN**, so rightnow becomes NaN when you add one to it.

Change your if statement to this:

```
if (!rightnow) { rightnow=1;}
```

This works because null is falsy in JavaScript.

There's actually one more problem with this line:

```
if (rightnow=='NaN') { rightnow=1;}
```

Let's say you actually stored NaN to a cookie. The jQuery cookies plugin magically turns the string 'NaN' saved in the cookie into the actual value NaN. So when you compare the string 'NaN' to the value NaN it will evaluate false. Check out what this fiddle prints in the console to see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/6VMqb/

Comment: Thanks, I have made the change. But I still see it begin with value '1' for a new session. Am I pulling in the global variable 'rightnow' value in the 'click' function correct?

Comment: The scope of `rightnow` looks correct. Try clearing your cookies completely to erase bad state. And stick a `console.log(rightnow);` after you read the cookie value for the first time and check the console to see what value it's reading.